# Erro "Transaction is required to perform this operation" ao inserir, editar ou excluir - Wildfly

Tags: jsf, cdi, wildfly

Então pessoal, estou quebrando a cabeça com esse erro à algum tempo e não consigo descobrir como arrumar... 
A situação é a seguinte, eu tinha esse projeto rodando no Tomcat e agora foi necessário migrar para o WildFly, a migração aparentemente foi ok, ele é um projeto em jsf, com cdi, hibernate e utilizando maven, fiz as alterações necessárias no .pom e outras dependências e ele está logando no projeto e as listagens estão funcionando normal, mas na hora de inserir, editar ou excluir está dando o erro abaixo:

```
4,913 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.lifecycle] (default task-45) #{back.salvar}: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: JBAS011469: Transaction is required to perform this operation (either use a transaction or extended persistence context): javax.faces.FacesException: #{back.salvar}: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: JBAS011469: Transaction is required to perform this operation (either use a transaction or extended persistence context)
at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:113) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:240) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:227) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:73) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:146) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:177) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:727) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: JBAS011469: Transaction is required to perform this operation (either use a transaction or extended persistence context)
at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
... 33 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: JBAS011469: Transaction is required to perform this operation (either use a transaction or extended persistence context)
at org.jboss.as.jpa.container.AbstractEntityManager.transactionIsRequired(AbstractEntityManager.java:867) [wildfly-jpa-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.as.jpa.container.AbstractEntityManager.persist(AbstractEntityManager.java:580) [wildfly-jpa-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
at com.inbit.projetobase.view.back.RecursoBack.salvar(RecursoBack.java:34) [classes:]
at com.inbit.projetobase.view.back.RecursoBack$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.salvar(Unknown Source) [classes:]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:275) [javax.el-3.0.0.jar:]
at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304) [javax.el-3.0.0.jar:]
at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
... 34 more

09:24:54,919 INFO  [stdout] (default task-45) 2014-09-16 09:24:54 ERROR context:218 - javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: JBAS011469: Transaction is required to perform this operation (either use a transaction or extended persistence context)

09:24:54,919 INFO  [stdout] (default task-45)   at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)

09:24:54,919 INFO  [stdout] (default task-45)   at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)

09:24:54,919 INFO  [stdout] (default task-45)   at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)

09:24:54,919 INFO  [stdout] (default task-45)   at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)

09:24:54,919 INFO  [stdout] (default task-45)   at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)

09:24:54,920 INFO  [stdout] (default task-45)   at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)

09:24:54,920 INFO  [stdout] (default task-45)   at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)

09:24:54,920 INFO  [stdout] (default task-45)   at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)

09:24:54,920 INFO  [stdout] (default task-45)   at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)

09:24:54,920 INFO  [stdout] (default task-45)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)

09:24:54,920 INFO  [stdout] (default task-45)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61)

09:24:54,920 INFO  [stdout] (default task-45)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)

09:24:54,920 INFO  [stdout] (default task-45)   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)

09:24:54,920 INFO  [stdout] (default task-45)   at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25)

09:24:54,921 INFO  [stdout] (default task-45)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:113)

09:24:54,921 INFO  [stdout] (default task-45)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56)

09:24:54,921 INFO  [stdout] (default task-45)   at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25)

09:24:54,921 INFO  [stdout] (default task-45)   at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45)

09:24:54,921 INFO  [stdout] (default task-45)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:61)

09:24:54,921 INFO  [stdout] (default task-45)   at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58)

09:24:54,925 INFO  [stdout] (default task-45)   ... 34 more

09:24:54,925 INFO  [stdout] (default task-45)
```

Lembrando que antes, quando rodava no Tomcat eu "cuidava" do entityManager, da seguinte maneira:

```
@DataRepository
@Inject
protected EntityManager entityManager;
```

E agora o Wildfly cuidaria disso para mim, certo? Passei a usar:

```
@PersistenceContext(name="pu", type=PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
protected EntityManager entityManager;
```

Alguém saberia dizer o que estou fazendo de errado? Sempre trabalhei com Tomcat e é primeira vez que migro um projeto para o Wildfly, e não consigo identificar qual equivoco estou cometendo... Já tentei usar @Statefull e @Stateless no CrudDAO mas sem sucesso(devo ter usado de maneira errada)

Segue as classes que estou utilizando:
CrudDAO:

```
@Named("crudDAO")
public class CrudDAO<E> implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(CrudDAO.class);

@PersistenceContext(name="pu", type=PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
protected EntityManager entityManager;

public CrudDAO() {
    super();
}

public void cadastrar(E entidade) {
    entityManager.persist(entidade);
}

public void atualizar(E entidade) {
    entityManager.merge(entidade);
}

public void deletar(E entidade) {
    entityManager.remove(entidade);
    entityManager.flush();;
}

public E buscarPorId(Class<E> clazz, Object id) {
    return entityManager.find(clazz, id);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<E> listar(Class<E> clazz) {
    List<E> lista = new ArrayList<E>();
    lista = entityManager.createQuery(" FROM " + clazz.getName())
            .getResultList();
    return lista;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<E> listarAtivos(Class<E> clazz) {
    List<E> lista = new ArrayList<E>();
    String hql = " FROM " + clazz.getName() + " WHERE ativo = :ativo";
    Query q = entityManager.createQuery(hql);
    q.setParameter("ativo", true);
    lista = q.getResultList();
    return lista;
}

public int total(E pesquisa) {
    Long count = 0L;

    try {
        Query q = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT count(*) FROM "
                + pesquisa.getClass().getName());
        count = (Long) q.getSingleResult();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Erro ao buscar total listagem lazy", e);
    }
    return count.intValue();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<E> listarLazy(E pesquisa, int startingAt, int maxPerPage,
        String sortField, String sortOrder) {
    List<E> lista = new ArrayList<E>();
    try {
        Query q = entityManager.createQuery("FROM "
                + pesquisa.getClass().getName());
        q.setFirstResult(startingAt);
        q.setMaxResults(maxPerPage);
        lista = q.getResultList();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Erro ao buscar listagem Lazy", e);
    }
    return lista;
}
```

}

CrudBO:

```
@Named("crudBO")
public class CrudBO<E extends BaseEntity> implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Inject
@Named("crudDAO")
protected CrudDAO<E> dao;

private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(CrudBO.class);

public CrudBO() {
    super();
}

public CrudBO(CrudDAO<E> dao) {
    super();
    this.dao = dao;
}

public String salvar(E entidade) {
    if (registroJaExiste(entidade)) {
        dao.atualizar(entidade);
        return "Editado com sucesso!";
    } else {
        dao.cadastrar(entidade);
        return "Cadastrado com sucesso!";
    }
}

public String deletar(E entidade) {
    dao.deletar(entidade);
    return "Excluído com sucesso!";
}

public E buscarPorId(Class<E> clazz, Long id) {
    return dao.buscarPorId(clazz, id);
}

public List<E> listar(Class<E> clazz) {
    return dao.listar(clazz);
}

public List<E> listarAtivos(Class<E> clazz) {
    return dao.listarAtivos(clazz);
}

public int total(E pesquisa) {
    return this.dao.total(pesquisa);
}

public List<E> listarLazy(E pesquisa, int startingAt, int maxPerPage,
        String sortField, String sortOrder) {
    inicializarCamposPesquisa(pesquisa);
    return this.dao.listarLazy(pesquisa, startingAt, maxPerPage, sortField,
            sortOrder);
}

protected void inicializarCamposPesquisa(E pesquisa) {
    //método que deverá ser implementado pelas classes filhas que quiserem filtrar os resultados no lazyList
}

protected boolean registroJaExiste(Object entidade) {
    Long id = null;
    try {
        id = (Long) entidade.getClass().getMethod("getId").invoke(entidade);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException
            | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException
            | SecurityException e) {
        LOGGER.error(
                "Problema ao utilizar Reflection para saber se registro já existe",
                e);
    }
    return id != null;
}
```

}

persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd" version="2.0">
<persistence-unit name="pu" transaction-type="JTA">
    <description>Minha conexao</description>
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:jboss/jdbc/Postgresql</jta-data-source>

    <properties>
        <!-- Datasource -->
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>

  <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
  <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
  <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>
  <property name="hibernate.transaction.flush_before_completion" value="true"/>

    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.inbit</groupId>
<artifactId>nomeDOProjeto</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>nomeDOProjeto</name>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <jetty.version>6.1.4</jetty.version>
</properties>


<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr250-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.faces-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2.Final</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>



<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
        <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr250-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-ejb-api_3.1_spec</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.faces-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.GA</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JPA Persistence Dependencies -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.0.10</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>5.0</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
        <artifactId>el-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>



<repositories>
    <!-- JBoss Repository used for Java EE 6 pieces -->
    <repository>
        <id>repository.jboss.org</id>
        <name>JBoss Repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/</url>
    </repository>

    <repository>
        <id>prime-repo</id>
        <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>

</repositories>


<build>
    <finalName>nomeDOProjeto</finalName>
    <plugins>

        <!-- Facilitates downloading source and javadoc in Eclipse -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.8</version>
            <configuration>
                <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- Plugin to run and test through maven -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.25</version>
            <configuration>
                <scanIntervalSeconds>3</scanIntervalSeconds>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- Ensures we are compiling at 1.7 level -->
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- Tomcat plugin for embedded tomcat -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <path>/${project.build.finalName}</path>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

Se precisarem que eu coloque mais alguma classe, é só falarem.

Desde já agradeço qualquer dica, ajuda e sugestões.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Use transações

Anote os métodos que fazem alguma inserção ou alteração nas entidades com `@Transactional`.

O JPA exige um contexto de transação para realizar essas alterações. Éste é um problema recorrente.

## Encontrando a anotação

Note que não é a anotação do Spring que estou me referindo, muitos frameworks possuem uma anotação com o mesmo nome, mas o pacote `javax` é reservado para o JavaEE.

O problema neste caso é que o Hibernate [`4.0.1.Final`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager/4.0.1.Final) depende do pacote [`jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction/jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec/1.0.0.Final), mas este não possui a anotação `@Transactional` no Jar. Porém, ela está presente a partir da versão 1.2 conforme verifiquei no pacote [`jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction/jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec/1.0.0.Final).

Então, o ideal seria atualizar a versão do Hibernate ou da API ou então procurar uma implementação da anotação que seja compatível com suas dependências.

Comment: Não seria `@Transactional`?

Comment: @GustavoCinque Isso mesmo, falou o `t`. Valew! ;)

Comment: Primeiramente gostaria de agradecer pela colaboração, mas não tenho essa opção de anotação aqui, só teria @TransactionAttribute e TransactionManagement... O que teria que adicionar para aparecer essa opção de anotação para mim?

Comment: @VictorCarvalho Não ter a opção significa que você não consegue importar a anotação `javax.transaction.Transacional`. Dê uma olhada em suas dependências, pois tenho um projeto aqui com Hibernate 4.6 e essa anotação é importada automaticamente pelo Maven através de resolução transitiva.

Comment: Até adicionei os dois jars abaixo e nada de aparecer... Vi na internet que esse @Transactional seria do Spring não?
     
    <dependency>
 <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
 <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
 <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>

<dependency>
 <groupId>org.apache.openejb</groupId>
 <artifactId>openejb-core-hibernate</artifactId>
 <version>4.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
Esse erro tá me tirando do sério.

Comment: @VictorCarvalho Não é do Spring. O pacote `javax` é reservado para o JavaEE. O problema é que o Hibernate [`4.0.1.Final`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager/4.0.1.Final) depende do [`jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction/jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec/1.0.0.Final) que não possui a `@Transactional`. No entanto, ela está presente a partir da versão [`jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction/jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec/1.0.0.Final).

Comment: E se ao invés de usar uma anotação `@Transactional` fosse utilizada a anotação `@Resource` acima de um atributo do tipo `UserTransaction`? Assim ele faria o controle de transação "à mão", mais ou menos assim: `userTransaction.begin();` ou `userTransaction.commit();` ou `userTransaction.rollback();`. Ou será que falei besteira? Qual a diferença de fazer desse jeito que eu falei ao invés de usar `@Transactional`?

Comment: Poxa meu caro, sem palavras para agradecer, adicionando o jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec no meu pom, apareceu a anotação e já funcionou para inserir e editar os dados! Só a exclusão que acabou dando erro, mas alterando para entityManager.remove(entityManager.merge(entidade)); funcionou tudo beleza. Brigadão mesmo! Forte abraço!
EDIT: Testando depois, vi que só atualizando a versão do hibernate já funcionou tudo certo também. =D

Comment: @Electus *Acho* que também seria possível.

Comment: Essa resposta é a correta da pergunta, @Victor que tal votar como melhor para encerrar a questão?